# Postgresql 10 and Ubuntu - Unable to postgresql server UP

Tags: ubuntu, postgresql

One day, My Postgresql server stopped working. Checked log. It was shutdown somehow.

```
root@ip_address:/# tail /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
2020-02-19 06:47:49.215 CET [23497] LOG:  received smart shutdown request
2020-02-19 06:47:49.477 CET [23497] LOG:  worker process: logical replication launcher (PID 23512) exited with exit code 1
2020-02-19 06:47:49.482 CET [23507] LOG:  shutting down
2020-02-19 06:47:49.546 CET [23497] LOG:  database system is shut down
```

**When I run,**

```
root@ip_address:/# psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

It complained that there are no files and directory. so I checked if my `postgresql` running.

```
root@ip_address:/# systemctl status postgresql
● postgresql.service - PostgreSQL RDBMS
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (exited) since Sun 2020-03-08 16:19:24 CET; 26min ago
  Process: 30136 ExecStart=/bin/true (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 30136 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 08 16:19:24 vps584959 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL RDBMS...
Mar 08 16:19:24 vps584959 systemd[1]: Started PostgreSQL RDBMS.
```

It was running. but, if I check postgresql cluster.

```
root@ip_address:/# pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 down   postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

It was **DOWN**

so I tried

```
root@ip_address:/# pg_ctlcluster 10 main start
 Error: Config owner (deploy:1003) and data owner (postgres:114) do not match, and config owner is not root
```

I wasn't able to make it work. then I tried.

```
sudo chown -R deploy:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/ && sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go= /var/lib/postgresql/10/
```

try again.

```
root@ip_address:/# pg_ctlcluster 10 main start
Job for postgresql@10-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

```
root@ip_address:/# systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
● postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Sun 2020-03-08 16:59:53 CET; 2min 52s ago
  Process: 31635 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 10-main start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 23497 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main...
Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 postgresql@10-main[31635]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/postgre
Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Mar 08 16:59:53 vps584959 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
```

Don't know what to do more. Is anybody had the same problem?

More infos.

```
root@ip_address:/var/run/postgresql# ls
total 0
drwxrwsr-x  3 postgres postgres   60 Feb 19 06:47 .
drwxr-xr-x 28 root     root     1060 Mar  8 13:58 ..
drwxr-s---  2 postgres postgres   40 Feb 19 06:47 10-main.pg_stat_tmp
```

```
root@vps584959:~# journalctl -xe
Mar 08 17:46:07 vps584959 sudo[2154]: root : TTY=pts/0 ; PWD=/root ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/systemctl start postgresql@10-main
Mar 08 17:46:07 vps584959 sudo[2154]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by root(uid=0)
Mar 08 17:46:07 vps584959 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main...
-- Subject: Unit postgresql@10-main.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit postgresql@10-main.service has begun starting up.
Mar 08 17:46:07 vps584959 postgresql@10-main[2157]: Error: Config owner (deploy:1003) and data owner (root:0) do not match, and config owner is not root
Mar 08 17:46:07 vps584959 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Mar 08 17:46:07 vps584959 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Mar 08 17:46:07 vps584959 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql@10-main.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit postgresql@10-main.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
Mar 08 17:46:07 vps584959 sudo[2154]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session closed for user root
Mar 08 17:46:08 vps584959 sshd[2152]: Invalid user ftp1 from x.x.x.x port 57060
Mar 08 17:46:08 vps584959 sshd[2152]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): check pass; user unknown
Mar 08 17:46:08 vps584959 sshd[2152]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.x.x.x
Mar 08 17:46:09 vps584959 sshd[2152]: Failed password for invalid user ftp1 from 159.89.196.75 port 57060 ssh2
Mar 08 17:46:10 vps584959 sshd[2152]: Received disconnect from x.x.x.x port 57060:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 08 17:46:10 vps584959 sshd[2152]: Disconnected from invalid user ftp1 159.89.196.75 port 57060 [preauth]
Mar 08 17:46:11 vps584959 sshd[2150]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.x.x.x  user=root
Mar 08 17:46:12 vps584959 sshd[2159]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=x.x.x.x  user=root
Mar 08 17:46:13 vps584959 sshd[2150]: Failed password for root from xx.xx.xx.xx port 20408 ssh2
```

**Update**
- still not working.

```
root@myserver:~# chown -R postgres:postgres /etc/postgresql/10/main/
root@myserver:~#
root@myserver:~#
root@myserver:~# pg_ctlcluster 10 main start
Job for postgresql@10-main.service failed because the service did not take the steps required by its unit configuration.
See "systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
root@myserver:~# systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
● postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Thu 2020-03-12 00:09:43 CET; 7s ago
  Process: 23767 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 10-main start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

root@vps584959:~# systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service
● postgresql@10-main.service - PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service; indirect; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: protocol) since Thu 2020-03-12 00:09:43 CET; 11min ago
  Process: 23767 ExecStart=/usr/bin/pg_ctlcluster --skip-systemctl-redirect 10-main start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

### Update 2

```
root@vps584959:~# journalctl -xe
--
-- Unit UNIT has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is RESULT.
Mar 14 13:55:16 vps584959 systemd[31170]: Startup finished in 171ms.
-- Subject: User manager start-up is now complete
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- The user manager instance for user 0 has been started. All services queued
-- for starting have been started. Note that other services might still be starting
-- up or be started at any later time.
--
-- Startup of the manager took 171927 microseconds.
Mar 14 13:55:17 vps584959 sshd[31156]: Failed password for root from 49.88.112.111 port 29693 ssh2
Mar 14 13:55:18 vps584959 sshd[31156]: Received disconnect from 49.88.112.111 port 29693:11:  [preauth]
Mar 14 13:55:18 vps584959 sshd[31156]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 49.88.112.111 port 29693 [preauth]
Mar 14 13:55:18 vps584959 sshd[31156]: PAM 2 more authentication failures; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=49.88.112.111  user=root
Mar 14 13:55:33 vps584959 sshd[31363]: pam_unix(sshd:auth): authentication failure; logname= uid=0 euid=0 tty=ssh ruser= rhost=134.17.94.237  user=root
Mar 14 13:55:35 vps584959 sshd[31363]: Failed password for root from 134.17.94.237 port 3684 ssh2
Mar 14 13:55:35 vps584959 sshd[31363]: Received disconnect from 134.17.94.237 port 3684:11: Bye Bye [preauth]
Mar 14 13:55:35 vps584959 sshd[31363]: Disconnected from authenticating user root 134.17.94.237 port 3684 [preauth]
Mar 14 13:55:43 vps584959 systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main...
-- Subject: Unit postgresql@10-main.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit postgresql@10-main.service has begun starting up.
Mar 14 13:55:43 vps584959 postgresql@10-main[31373]: Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/10/main -l /var/log/p
Mar 14 13:55:43 vps584959 postgresql@10-main[31373]: 2020-03-14 13:55:43.696 CET [31378] FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" must be owned by the da
Mar 14 13:55:43 vps584959 postgresql@10-main[31373]: 2020-03-14 13:55:43.698 CET [31378] LOG:  database system is shut down
Mar 14 13:55:43 vps584959 postgresql@10-main[31373]: pg_ctl: could not start server
Mar 14 13:55:43 vps584959 postgresql@10-main[31373]: Examine the log output.
Mar 14 13:55:43 vps584959 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Can't open PID file /var/run/postgresql/10-main.pid (yet?) after start: No such file or directory
Mar 14 13:55:43 vps584959 systemd[1]: postgresql@10-main.service: Failed with result 'protocol'.
Mar 14 13:55:43 vps584959 systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL Cluster 10-main.
-- Subject: Unit postgresql@10-main.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://www.ubuntu.com/support
--
-- Unit postgresql@10-main.service has failed.
--
-- The result is RESULT.
```

and,

```
root@vps584959:~# cat /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
.
.
2020-03-12 00:09:43.609 CET [23773] FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" must be owned by the database user or root
2020-03-12 00:09:43.611 CET [23773] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
2020-03-14 13:55:43.696 CET [31378] FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" must be owned by the database user or root
2020-03-14 13:55:43.698 CET [31378] LOG:  database system is shut down
pg_ctl: could not start server
Examine the log output.
root@vps584959:~#
```

Comment: Postgres is complaining because `/etc/postgresql/10/main` is not owned neither by `root` nor `postgres`.

Comment: so how do I approach this problem?

Comment: Do a recursive `chown` to `postgres:postgres` for both `/etc/postgres` and `/var/lib/postgres`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`systemctl status postgresql` is not useful to check for your postgresql
instances, as it's just an umbrella service.
You want `systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service` in
your case. It would correctly show the status as inactive when the instance is down.

As explained at the start of `/lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service`:

```
$ head /lib/systemd/system/postgresql@.service
# systemd service template for PostgreSQL clusters. The actual instances will
# be called "postgresql@version-cluster", e.g. "postgresql@9.3-main". The
# variable %i expands to "version-cluster", %I expands to "version/cluster".
# (%I breaks for cluster names containing dashes.)

[Unit]
Description=PostgreSQL Cluster %i
AssertPathExists=/etc/postgresql/%I/postgresql.conf
RequiresMountsFor=/etc/postgresql/%I /var/lib/postgresql/%I
PartOf=postgresql.service
```

As for the original problem of the server not starting, it's because `postgres` should own both the configuration files and the data directory and everything in it. For some reason, you/someone/something reassigned these files to a `deploy` user, and that can't work with the way PosgreSQL is set up in Ubuntu/Debian. Just leave the permissions and owner as they're originally set.

---

Pper comments about the SSL key file:
The following error shows that the permissions and ownership must be restored on the SSL private key file:

PostgreSQL error:

```
FATAL:  private key file "/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key" must be owned by the database user or root
```

Commands to restore ownership and permissions:

```
$ sudo chown root:ssl-cert /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
$ sudo chmod 640 /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
```

Comment: so I did this.►►► 'sudo chown -R deploy:deploy /var/lib/postgresql/10/ && sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go= /var/lib/postgresql/10/' -  Anything I can do for this more? I assume Ubuntu update made this all mess... :(

Comment: @JinLim: The files that you have chowned to `deploy:deploy` must be chowned to `postgres:postgres` instead.

Comment: Nope. Did not work. ►►►'sudo chown -R postgres:postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/ && sudo chmod -R u=rwX,go= /var/lib/postgresql/10/'

Comment: @JinLim: That's not sufficient. The configuration files in `/etc/postgresql/10/main` need to be reassigned to postgres as well. Otherwise there will still be the first error you mentioned: _Error: Config owner (deploy:1003) and data owner (postgres:114) do not match, and config owner is not root_

Comment: please tell me how I do it. or some reference doc I can follow?

Comment: @JinLim: `chown -R postgres:postgres /etc/postgresql/10/main/`

Comment: Thanks but still not working.. updated questions.

Comment: @JinLim: the result of `journalctl -xe` seems to be needed since `systemctl status postgresql@10-main.service` gives so little information now. Also `/var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log` might be informative too, depending on how far the startup sequence went.

Comment: I updated Infos on to question. I can see it's `user` permision issue. but I don't know how to solve. why is this happening? I am `root` user.

Comment: @JinLim: please see edit.

Comment: Thanks Daniel! It solved my issue!

Answer (score -2):

Yes. Its Cause of permission issues to postgresql folders on your system. try with 0777

Comment: No, Never use 777 for anything, ever, not even testing. It is too destructive. Ignore anyone who recommends it because they are mistaken.